# Continuous integration and Gradle: external project as dependency

Tags: gradle, continuous-integration

I have a Gradle-based project with a external project as dependency.

**settings.gradle**

```
include ':app'
include ':mylibrary'
project(':mylibrary').projectDir = new File('/path/to/my/library')
```

I'm developing `mylibrary` at the same time as my app, this is the reason why I include it in my project this way, instead of as dependency (I would have to upload the artifact in each change or copy the `jar` to `libs` folder, and that is tedious).

My problem is that when I commit changes of my app, Jenkins build fails because it can't find the module `mylibrary` (obviously, beacuse it is in my local file system).

How should I handle with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved the same problem this way.

Add `mylibrary` as a proper dependency in `app`. The `app` build will try to pull the library from your configured remote Maven or Ivy repo(s).

When you change `mylibrary`, you may want to make that change visible to `app` immediately, without publishing to the binary repo. You can accomplish this by using the `:mylibrary:publishToMavenLocal` task, which will put the binary lib in your `~/.m2/reposity`. This only takes one extra command so it's not too bad, I think. This assumes the new Maven publisher is being used in `mylibrary`:

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
```

Next, `app` needs to be instructed to fetch dependencies from there:

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    //other repos
}
```

The `app:compileJava` task should now check your local Maven repo first, before checking remote repos.

I find this approach is preferable to the answer by taringamberini, because you don't have to publish changes to `library` which are not ready for customer release. You can even test that your changes to `mylibrary` don't break `app`, before you merge library changes to `master`.

(You *don't* want to publish changes to the binary repo, which are not in `master`. That would be a recipe for disaster...)

Answer (score 1):

You should work with 2 gradle projects in your workspace:

- `mylibrary`
- `myapp` (with a dependency on `mylibrary`)

When `mylibrary` is modified you should test it and, if test have passed, commit it to source repository and to binary repository. (If you didn't want do that manually you might configure 3 Jenkins jobs, build <-- test <-- deploy to binary repository, configuring a little continuous-delivery pipeline).

Next when `mylibrary` is modified you should test it and, if test have passed, commit it to repository. Such commit triggers a Jenkins build and because `mylibrary` exists both in the source and binary repositories, it will compile successfully.

You may version `mylibrary` adopting [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/) and managing the last version of `mylibrary` with graddle's [Dynamic Versions or Changing Modules](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:dynamic_versions_and_changing_modules) feature.